# My Laptop Won't Stay Asleep!

Tags: 12.04, suspend

I'm using 12.04.3 on a Toshiba satellite c55d-a and it has 4 GB RAM and a 500 GB hard disk.

It seems like it wants to go to sleep when you click suspend but it has a habit of waking up after 10 secs on suspend. Is it because I have too new of a laptop model or what? I did go to power settings and changed it like I was supposed to, but its still doing the same thing it was before I did change the power settings its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Search for Power in dash from that you can change the suspend time(suspend when inactive for) .

[image]

Try the below command to suspend your pc for 1 hour,

```
sudo rtcwake -u -s 3600 -m mem
```